# Customize StyleCop message for new file generation

Tags: stylecop, automated-refactoring

Stylecop puts a copyright message when new file is created.
Sample message is specified below

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
// 
// TODO: Update copyright text.
// 
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------

I want to include company name, and default message (instead of update the copyright text).

How to customize the above message ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the StyleCop settings dialog (in the project context menu), and configure your company details in the Company Information tab. This will add the following settings to the Settings.StyleCop file:

```
<AnalyzerSettings>
    <StringProperty Name="CompanyName">Company</StringProperty>
    <StringProperty Name="Copyright">Copyright</StringProperty>
</AnalyzerSettings>
```

Then if required you can configure the ReSharper StyleCop settings (in the ReSharper Code Cleanup options) to either leave the header alone, insert it if missing, update the copyright info, or replace the header completely.

Answer (score 0):

ReSharper doesn't do this by default. You either installed StyleCop (then your question should be about StyleCope), or changed some options.

Normally you change file header here: ReSharper | Options -> Code Editing | File Header Text

Comment: I am following the link http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2010/12/automating-file-header-information-with-resharper/, but could not set it up.

Comment: If you have StyleCop, then you need to ask a question about StyleCop. It overrides ReSharper settings.

Comment: updated the question. Can you specify workaround for stylecop ?

Comment: Unfortunately no. You'd better file a new question on StyleCop, this way you'll have more chances for an answer.